# Aptana Studio 3 - Projects on the local network

Tags: networking, debian, aptana

I installed Aptana Studio 3, I'm having trouble importing projects on the local network. Example: we have 2 computers and the first is the server with all files. Php project created some. I would like to open this project created in the local network. Thank you.

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer, please vote for the best answer and accept it. This is a way to thank who helps you and encourage people to help others here on stackoverflow. @Carlos Bigaran

Answer (score 4):

You can import an existing set of files into Aptana Studio by creating a new project and pointing Aptana Studio to the home directory for your existing project. Reference [HERE](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Importing+an+Existing+Project)

**Using the Import Wizard**

To import an existing project into Studio:

1. From the **File** menu, select **Import... > Existing Folder as New Project**.
2. In the **Directory** text field, browse to the folder that contains your Dreamweaver or HomeSite project.
3. Name your project.
4. Choose the natures for your project. You will want to choose Web in almost every case, plus the type of your project (PHP, Rails, etc)
5. Click the **Finish** button.

---

**Using Promote to Project**

Promoting a folder to a project allow you to take any folder on disk and convert it into a project. You will see the project in your workspace, but the files live on disk in the former spot.

1. Open the Project Explorer view.
2. Expand the local filesystem node to the folder in question.
3. Choose **Promote to Project**.
4. Name your project appropriately and click **OK**.
5. Depending on the type of project, you may need to change the "natures" associated with the project.

---

**Using Source Control systems**

You can also import projects from a Source Control system if you use it. [CVS](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/CVS), [Git](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Git), [Mercurial](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Mercurial), [Perforce](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Perforce) and [Subversion](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Subversion) are supported natively.
(Click on the links for specific instructions for each Source Control system)

Other Source Control systems may be supported by using specific plugins.
For example [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) by using [BzrEclipse](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrEclipse) (thanks mutil for this)

Comment: Bazaar support is also possible with [BzrEclipse](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrEclipse)

Comment: yes, it is extendable by using plugins. I talked about possible import methods already included in Aptana Studio by default.

Comment: This solution works to an extent, but I have found if the source on the network is down when I open Aptana, then I have to remove the project and import all over again.